# Verify a proof for graded variant of Nakayama's lemma

Tags: solution-verification, commutative-algebra

Is the following proof of a graded variant of Nakayama's lemma correct? It's almost the same as the answer in [Nakayama Lemma, graded version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582303/nakayama-lemma-graded-version). This proof is so simple that it makes me doubt whether it is correct. Is it because $S_\bullet$ has no negative degree homogenous elements and hence the proof is simpler than  [how to prove a graded version of Nakayama's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964615/how-to-prove-a-graded-version-of-nakayamas-lemma)?

> Let $S_\bullet = k[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be the polynomial ring of $n+1$ indeterminates and $S_+ = (x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be the irrelevant ideal of $S_\bullet$. Let $M_\bullet$ be a finitely generated graded module over $S_\bullet$ such that $M_\bullet = S_+M_\bullet$. Then
> $$
> M_\bullet = 0
> $$

> Proof: Since $M_\bullet$ is finitely generated, suppose $m$ is a homogeneous element with lowest degree. Then from $M_\bullet = S_+M_\bullet$, we have
> $$
> m = \sum s_i m_i
> $$
> with $s_i \in S_+$ and $m_i \in M_\bullet$ and $\operatorname{deg}(m) = \operatorname{deg}(s_i) + \operatorname{deg}(m_i)$.
> But $\operatorname{deg}(s_i) > 0$ gives $\operatorname{deg}(m) > \operatorname{deg}(m_i)$ hence it contradicts with our assumption.$\square$